# Python preencher valores com dados de outras colunas

Tags: python

[Tenho uma planilha Excel que já carreguei no Jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfqU8.png)

| FAMILIA | GENERO | ESPECIE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | NaN | Spizaetus tyrannus |
| Ariidae | Notarius | NaN |

Preciso preencher os valores Nan da coluna ESPECIE pelas colunas do lado esquerdo a ela (GENERO, FAMILIA, ORDEM e etc. até DOMINIO), quando tiver Nan, eu gostaria de preencher pela coluna ao lado, se a coluna ao lado tiver nan eu gostaria de preencher pela coluna antecedente, e assim por diante.

Em resumo, se não tiver a ESPECIE, preencha ESPECIE pelo GENERO, se GENERO for Nan, preencha ESPECIE pela FAMILIA, se FAMILA for Nan, preencha ESPECIE pela ORDEm e assim por diante. Ao final queria que fosse gerado outra tabela excel com a mesma quantidade de linhas e colunas daquela que estou trabalhando.

Já tentei:

```
temp = tabela['ESPECIE'].mask(tabela['GENERO'].isna()).bfill()
```

```
tabela['ESPECIE'] = tabela['ESPECIE'].fillna(temp)
```

```
display (temp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes substituir a coluna da espécie pela última coluna da tabela depois de fazer ffill no eixo das colunas.

```
tabela['ESPECIE'] = tabela.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
```

Answer (score -3):

Usei essa solução:

```
table2['SPECIE'] = table2.SPECIE.fillna(table2.GENERO).fillna(table2.FAMILY).fillna(table2.ORDER).fillna(table2.CLASS).fillna(table2.SUPERCLASS).fillna(table2.SUBFILO).fillna(table2.FILO).fillna(table2.KINGDOM).fillna(table2.DOMAIN)
```